# How to use the Select interaction without applying style

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Is there any way to use the `Select` interaction of OpenLayers without changing feature style?

I am only interested in using events of that interaction, when hovering.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenLayers has an very good documentation. Reading the API helps a lot.

From [ol.interaction.Selection](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html):

> By default, selected features are styled differently, so this interaction can be used for visual highlighting, as well as selecting features for other actions, such as modification or output
>
> Style for the selected features. By default the default edit style is used (see ol.style).

So you can work around that by providing the same style to the select interaction that is defined on your map. The default style definition is listed in the doc of [ol.style](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.html).

```js
      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });

      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        })
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
      
      var styleFunction = function(feature) {
         var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
           color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
         });
         var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
           color: '#3399CC',
           width: 1.25
         });
         var styles = [
           new ol.style.Style({
             image: new ol.style.Circle({
               fill: fill,
               stroke: stroke,
               radius: 5
             }),
             fill: fill,
             stroke: stroke
           })
         ];
         return styles;
      }

      var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
        style: styleFunction
      });
      map.addInteraction(select);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Select Features</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually tried something similar, but it did not work...

style: (aFeature, aResolution) => aFeature.getStyleFunction()

Comment: the feature does not necessarily have a style. It can be on the source too and falls back to the default style definition if not defined. So it's maybe easiest for you to define a style, put it on the source and give it to the Select too.